# How to draw icons or similar in Canvas?

Tags: java, android, android-canvas

Is there any way to draw some icons or something in Canvas inside points or circles? For example a company´s logo? Could be with bitmap or similar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the different methods from Canvas "draw()" and you just have to take care of your bounds. Use for example:

```
mCanvas.drawBitmap(Bitmap bitmap, float left, float top, Paint paint);
mCanvas.drawCircle(float cx, float cy, float radius, Paint paint);
```

Check it here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html